# Using DISTINCT inside a COUNT with CakePHP 3

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new with CakePHP 3 and I want to know how I can use a DISTINCT inside a COUNT such as the following SQL query.

```
SELECT `column_one`, COUNT(DISTINCT `column_two`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `column_one`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can simply do

```
$query = $table->find()
->select([
    'column_one',
    'count' => "COUNT(DISTINCT `column_two`)"
])
->group(['column_one']);
```

but if you want to use cakephp sql function you can do

```
...
'count' => $query->func()->count('DISTINCT `column_two`')
....
```

Comment: It would be a bit clearer if you included a complete solution using the native CakePHP count() function; it's not immediately obvious from your solution that `$query` needs to be instantiated separately.  Like so:

$query = $table->find('all');
$query = $query->select([
'column_one',
'count' => $query->func()->count('DISTINCT `column_two`')]);